# SELECT query on a table with a space in the name using SQSH

Tags: sql-server, sqsh

I'm using SQSH (version 2.1) on Ubuntu 10.04 to connect to a MSSQL database using a command like this:

```
sqsh -S server -U user -P password -D database
```

I have a table called My Table, but I cannot find a way to run a SELECT query on it. This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM 'My Table'
go
```

Output: Incorrect syntax near 'My Table'. (I get the same for double quotes)

```
\set t="My Table"
SELECT * FROM $t
go
```

Output: Invalid object name 'My'. (Which is weird because if I do \echo $t, I get the full table name)

```
SELECT * FROM My\\ Table
go
```

Output: Invalid object name 'My'.

```
SELECT * FROM [My Table]
go
```

Output: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.

This last command works fine for table names without any spaces.

UPDATE: other commands work fine e.g. I can get the table description with:

```
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'My Table'
go
```

Comment: You're using Sybase and you have a table with spaces on the name?

Comment: No, it's an MSSQL database. Sorry, maybe the tags were misleading.

Comment: Can you test what happens if you remove the space from the table name?

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of the question: there are other tables without spaces in their names, and everything works fine for them i.e. I can use the name on it's own, or wrap it in square brackets, or assign it to a variable and use that, and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found [the solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php#105843). I had to add the following 2 lines to /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

Answer (score 17):

Putting the table name in quotes doesn't work in MS SQL Server.
The correct way is using `[ ]`:

```
SELECT * FROM [My Table]
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the question, that didn't work for me. I was missing some configuration settings (see my answer), and once I had those, the SELECT query worked with either quotes or square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

Im using SQL 2008R2, and the following works for me

```
['table name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to ON when using SQL Server. For more info about QUOTED_IDENTIFIER see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately it did not help.