# Incorrect syntax near 'FROM' Keyword. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have tried debugging of code and commenting, but I can't seem to find the problem. [I am getting the this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12CzV.png)

> Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'.

My code:

```
public List<string> GetTableColumns(string tableName)
{
    List<string> colCollection = new List<string>();

    IDataReader reader = null;

    using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName))
    {
        using (reader = MyDB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            foreach (DataRow r in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
            {
                colCollection.Add(r["ColumnName"].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    return colCollection;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this to see what `tableName` actually is? go do that and report back

Comment: What is the name of the Table and what is being passed as `tableName`?

Comment: OT if you just want the columns, add a WHERE 1=0. You do apparently not want any rows, so why get them?

Comment: added my answer can you try out

Comment: I don't think error is in the query. Can you post the function details which is GetSqlStringCommand?

Comment: Generic debugging advice for concatenated queries: what *is* the resulting query text exactly? Pay special attention to missing or extra spaces and "special characters"

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you to format string properly like using string format as below and also check tablename is present or not

```
 public List<string> GetTableColumns(string tableName)
 {
   if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableName))
   {
    string query = string.Format( "SELECT * FROM  [{0}]",tableName);
    // or use string interpolation
    string query = $"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]";
    //rest of the code execute reader  
    //return collection of string   
   }
   return new List<string>();
  }
```

Add `[]` around table name because table name in sql may contains white space example. `SELECT * FROM [My Table]` , that also can cause issue (check this answer for more detail : [SELECT query on a table with a space in the name using SQSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926673/select-query-on-a-table-with-a-space-in-the-name-using-sqsh))

Comment: this is the same as `"SELECT * FROM " + tableName`, why do you think this can help?

Comment: @vasily.sib - but its more clear and i added code to check tableName is empty or not

Comment: I very doubt about `more clear`. And checking for empty is no sence. `"some string " + string.Empty`, `"some string " + null` and `$"some string {null}"` will produce same string

Comment: @vasily.sib - you are correct but if you send "select * from (no value in empty string)" then sql gives you error , that also cause of issue as per error given by OP in question

Comment: @vasily.sib - as per this `Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'.` error can be cause if there is not table value given or may be table value contains wrong input

Comment: you are right, but this is not a "formatting" issue, so your answer is misleading. I think your answer should contains information from your comment (the one with _select * from (no value in empty string)_) and not what it contains now.

Comment: and one more. Is this `[{tableName}]` escape sequence is valid for MySQL, for example?

Answer (score 0):

As @PranayRana mention in comments to his answer, this issue is mostly because of that `tableName` parameter, passed to `GetTableColumns()`, is `null`, or empty string. I'm 98% sure.

You need to check parameter value before you use it. But instead returning a default value (empty list, for example), I prefer throwing an exception (because it is, *literally*, exceptional situation), like this:

```
public List<string> GetTableColumns(string tableName)
{
    if (tableName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tableName));
    if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(tableName))
        throw new ArgumentException("Table name can't be empty!", nameof(tableName));

    List<string> colCollection = new List<string>();

    using (var cmd = MyDB.GetSqlStringCommand($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}"))
    using (var reader = MyDB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        foreach (DataRow r in reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows)
            colCollection.Add(r["ColumnName"].ToString());

    return colCollection;
}
```

One more thing. You also need to handle escaping of your SQL commands. For example, you can't just `SELECT * FROM User;` with MS SQL Server, you need to `SELECT * FROM [User];`, or even `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[User];` sometimes. This may vary from DBMS to DBMS.

As advise, I recomend you to learn something about **ORMs**, like `EntityFramework` or `NHibernate`, because you will be then free from this **DBMS**-relative stuff like syntax, or escaping sequences.